# How to change Post ID during import

Tags: permalinks

I'm importing posts from a Joomla v1.5 site using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/joomla-15-importer/ (The goal is to clone the site in WordPress then switch off Joomla)

On both sites the permalink structure is /%category%/%post_id%-%postname%/

Of course, when I import I am getting a different post ID in WordPress than existed in Joomla.

Can I change post ID manually in the DB after import? Aside from .htaccess file with a huge number of rules (one per article!) is there another workaround for this issue? Any comments/suggestions?

Thanks,
Alastair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) function in WP accepts special `import_id` field in arguments and will try to use that ID, rather than automatically generating new one.

This is easy to use when writing import code yourself, but I have no idea how easy would it be to with that plugin. You could try suggesting this as a feature to plugin's eveloper.